# Why doesn't KeepAlive work in my .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, keep-alive

I was trying to add `KeepAlive` directive to my `.htaccess` file, like this:

```
KeepAlive on
KeepAliveTimeout 15
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

All it did was disable the website.

I'm assuming, I had to insert that code within some tags, but what are those tags? What should be the complete code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeepAlive is just available in 'server config'. It means you can set it just in the global server configurations, it is usually in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf or /etc/apache2/...

Look to the documentation, there is ever explanation what are available locations for each configuration parameter.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html

Comment: So that means that .htaccess is NOT the file where this should be added, @Martin?

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that in .htaccess, the locations are http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context